# Why does setInterval not wait for specified time?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

When I goto `localhost:3000`, the `broadcast` event is not waiting for each 3 seconds to broadcast the data. It immediately sends all the values.
Ideally it should have taken `3*500 = 1500` seconds, but it emits the 500 data in around 2 seconds.

Why is it happening so?

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log('New user connected');

    socket.on('createMessage', function (message) {
        console.log(message);
        io.emit('newMessage', { from: message.message, createdAt: new Date().getTime() });
    });

    setInterval(function(){
      socket.emit('broadcast', {message: track()} , 3000);
    });

    socket.on('disconnect', function () { console.log('Disconnected from client'); });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two problems in your code, the first one is that you send the interval time parameter to the emit function instead of setInterval, you can fix it by writing

```
setInterval(function(){
   socket.emit('broadcast', {message: track()}); // notice the 3000 is not here
}, 3000);
```

But now it creates the second problem, what happens after the disconnect? the interval is still executing every 3000 MS and it's a memory leak!
You should also invalidate your interval

```
const interval = setInterval(...);

socket.on('disconnect', function () {
 clearInterval(interval);
 console.log('Disconnected from client');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

There's an error in your `setInterval` function syntax. Use this,

```
setInterval(function(){
    socket.emit('broadcast', {message: track()});
}, 3000)
```